# Преобразование String to Int без parseInt

Tags: java

Нужно реализовать метод без использования parseInt. Подскажите основной алгоритм как это сделать ?

Comment: нужно пробегаться по строке с конца на начало извлекая символ `str.charAt(i)` умножая на разряд (1, 10, 100 и т.д.) - всё это складывая  в переменную общую

Comment: или Integer.valueOf)), хотя он вроде юзает parseInt

Comment: А если усложнить задачу и переводить надо из string to double так не используя parseDouble

Comment: @ТимурЗалимов тогда это будет нерешаемая задача для современных компьютеров.

Comment: @ТимурЗалимов тогда это другая задача и про нее нужно задать другой вопрос.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, почему? :-) делаешь сплит по разделителю получаешь целую и дробную части в виде целых чисел - дальше из них double собираешь. Но вопрос будет уже другой, да

Comment: @Grundy просто шЮтка-минЮтка

Answer (score 2):

Очередная лаба.

Значит для начала проверяем, является ли первый символ символом "-" и если является, то какой-нибудь переменной выставляем флажок. Это будет признаком знаковости. Чтобы все опупели, можно проверять символы юникода, похожие на минус - их около 2х десятков: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Pd (был какой-то китайский сайт с более приличным списком, но мне искать его лень)

Далее, инициализируем наш аккумулятор в 0 и начинаем его заполнять цифирками. Если встречаем цифирку - по сложнейшей формуле используем ее аккум=аккум*10+цифирка. Этому учат где-то в районе 3-го класса средней школы.

Если мы встречаем точку или запятую, то ее можно принять за дробную часть. Это, между прочим, реальная потребность для написания подобных велосипедов - если надо парсить числа вида 100.000.000,10 или 100,000,000.10.

Чтобы препод писал кипятком, то надо правильно обрабатывать ошибки. К примеру, пробелы в записях вида 100 000 000 можно игнорить, а можно выбрасывать ошибки. Можно попытаться обрабатывать нецифровые символы - выбрасывать ошибки или подставлять их как математические константы (к примеру, число Пи), парсить слова вида "одна тысяча девятьсот тысяч семьсот миллионов трицать пи копеек без ндс" - все, что душе угодно. В общем, можно развлекаться как умеешь.

Comment: Или просто заюзать исходный код `parseInt`...

Comment: А требуется лаба или копипаста? Эдак диплом сразу купить можно

Comment: Я не понимаю о чем вы

Answer (score 1):

По следам идеи @АлексейШиманский - я бы написал так:

```
private int convert(String s) {
   s=s.trim(); //освобождаемся от пробелов спереди и сзади
   int digit;
   int value=0;
   int order=1;
   for(int i=s.length()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
      digit=charToDigit(s.charAt(i));
      if(digit < 0)
         throw new NumberFormatException();
      value+=digit*order;
      order*=10;
   }
   return value;
}

private int charToDigit(final char ch) {
   final String digits="0123456789";
   return digits.indexOf(ch);
}
```

**Update**

Можно тупо выдрать исходники `parseInt()` (параметр `radix` - здесь означает основание):

```
public static int parseInt(String s, int radix)
            throws NumberFormatException
{
    if (s == null) {
        throw new NumberFormatException("null");
    }

    if (radix < Character.MIN_RADIX) {
        throw new NumberFormatException("radix " + radix +
                                        " less than Character.MIN_RADIX");
    }

    if (radix > Character.MAX_RADIX) {
        throw new NumberFormatException("radix " + radix +
                                        " greater than Character.MAX_RADIX");
    }

    int result = 0;
    boolean negative = false;
    int i = 0, len = s.length();
    int limit = -Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int multmin;
    int digit;

    if (len > 0) {
        char firstChar = s.charAt(0);
        if (firstChar < '0') { // Possible leading "-"
            if (firstChar == '-') {
                negative = true;
                limit = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            } else
                throw NumberFormatException.forInputString(s);

            if (len == 1) // Cannot have lone "-"
                throw NumberFormatException.forInputString(s);
            i++;
        }
        multmin = limit / radix;
        while (i < len) {
            // Accumulating negatively avoids surprises near MAX_VALUE
            digit = Character.digit(s.charAt(i++),radix);
            if (digit < 0) {
                throw NumberFormatException.forInputString(s);
            }
            if (result < multmin) {
                throw NumberFormatException.forInputString(s);
            }
            result *= radix;
            if (result < limit + digit) {
                throw NumberFormatException.forInputString(s);
            }
            result -= digit;
        }
    } else {
        throw NumberFormatException.forInputString(s);
    }
    return negative ? result : -result;
}
```

Comment: а разве нет никакой встроенной функции `charToDigit`?

Comment: Поищите, как найдете дайте знать :)

Comment: Судя по всему: [`Character.getNumericValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char)) :-)

Comment: А что так сложно-то `charToDigit` делается? `ch - '0'` же...